# Write a query to get for each person, for each date - what is his last out_time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table: EMPLOYEE

```
EMP_ID           DATE                          IN_TIME        OUT_TIME

111                     01-Jan-2019               09:00               12:00

111                     01-Jan-2019               13:00               16:00

111                     01-Jan-2019               16:30               18:00

111                     02-Jan-2019               08:00               11:00

111                     02-Jan-2019               12:00               17:00

222                    01-Jan-2019               10:00               14:00

222                     01-Jan-2019               15:00               20:00

222                    02-Jan-2019               08:30               11:30

222                     02-Jan-2019               13:00               18:30
```

Write a query to get for each person, for each date - what is his last out_time?

Expected output:

```
EMP_ID           DATE                          IN_TIME        OUT_TIME

111                     01-Jan-2019               16:30               18:00

111                     02-Jan-2019               12:00               17:00

222                     01-Jan-2019               15:00               20:00

222                     02-Jan-2019               13:00               18:30
```

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()`:

```
select emp_id, convert(date, out_time), max(out_time)
from t
group by emp_id, convert(date, out_time);
```